# Session redirect making links duplicate wording

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have a session redirect after a user has successfully registered and it takes them to a page called register_success.php. In that page, I have a link to take the user back to the index page. When I click on that link it duplicates my sites name. It says something like this. example.com/example.com/index.php.

Is there anyway I can get this to not do this?

My session redirect is like this..

```
Session::flash('register_success', 'Congratulations, you have successfully created an account!');
    Redirect::to('register_success.php');
```

Session class

```
class Session {
public static function exists($name) {
    return (isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
}
public static function put($name, $value) {
    return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
}
public static function get($name) {
    return $_SESSION[$name];
}
public static function delete($name) {
    if(self::exists($name)) {
        unset($_SESSION[$name]);
    }
}

public static function flash($name, $string = '') {
    if(self::exists($name)) {
        $session = self::get($name);
        self::delete($name);
        return $session;
    } else {
        self::put($name, $string);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Like this? http://example.com ?

Comment: like `http://example.com/path to register_success.php`

Comment: It loops again and won't even go to `example.com/register_success.php`

Comment: what exact code you are trying with absolute url?

Comment: Just like in the code I posted. `Session::flash('register_success', 'Congratulations, you have successfully created an account!');
    Redirect::to('example.com/register_success.php');`

Comment: This is being processed from a form

Comment: you also need to include http://

Comment: It took me to register_success page, but the link on that page is still looping and when I got to the register_success page, the session message wasn't there.

Comment: are you using laravel ? because i think these functions are of laravel . try setting by php function and see what happens

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: php doesnt have Session::flash static class ... its in laravel framework or you have created it .. now what i am telling is try setting it by php session functino